# Password Authentification does not working

Tags: php, yii

Hi there this is totally a very basic question but i am new to yii framework and php. I have customized the    `UserIdentity.php` like this

> private $_id;
>
> ```
> public function authenticate()  {
>
>         $username=strtolower($this->username);
>         $user=  User::model()->find('Lower(username)=?',array($username));
>         if($user===NULL)
>             $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
>         else if($user->validatePassword($this->password))
>             $this->errorcode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
>         else
>         {
>             $this->_id=$user->id;
>             $this->username=$user->username;
>             $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
>         }
>         return $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE ;        /*
>         $users=array(             // username => password             'demo'=>'demo',             'admin'=>'admin',       );
>   if(!isset($users[$this->username]))
>       $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
>   elseif($users[$this->username]!==$this->password)
>       $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;      else
>       $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;      return !$this->errorCode;
>
>         */    }
> ```

and in `User.php` model i write like this

```
 public function validatePassword($password)
        {
            return $this->hashPassword($password)===$this->password;
        }
        public function hashPassword($password)
        {
            return md5($password) ;
        }
```

but when i type password it does not authenticate, normally the username and password is demo but i cant figure it out that whats going wrong here. Please bear me as a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this...

```
else if(!$user->validatePassword($this->password))
        $this->errorcode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
```

there should be **!** with else if(). and make sure when you are adding new user the password should be encrypted using **md5()**. that also just check it out in db..

Comment: check your database.. is it really encoding? if yes then try to register new user and check..

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem in this line...

```
 $user=  User::model()->find('Lower(username)=?',array($username));
```

try to change it with this

```
$user=  User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$username));
```